# Why doesn't Tensorflow have if conditions?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Recently I was implementing a custom loss function in Tensorflow and I realized, Tensorflow doesn't have if conditions. I feel like if conditions are such an inherent programming feature why would Tensorflow developers not have such a fundamental feature in such a big project?

Comment: Tensorflow 2.0 supports eager execution and Python control flow such as conditions and loops. I highly recommend upgrading if you commonly need such "complicated" control flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TensorFlow is not thought to be eagerly executed as python is. So the framework provides extra functions to kind o simulate eager functionalities.

Some examples are:

- `tf.cond(condition, true_fn, flase_fn)`: In case the condition is false it will execute the `false_fn`, otherwise the `true_fn`

```
z = tf.multiply(a, b)
result = tf.cond(x < y, lambda: tf.add(x, z), lambda: tf.square(y))
```

- `tf.while`

```
i = tf.constant(0)
c = lambda i: tf.less(i, 10)
b = lambda i: tf.add(i, 1)
r = tf.while_loop(c, b, [i])
```

Source: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/

Comment: My question is essentially, why do normal "if and else" conditions don't work like in Python or any other language. Why did the developers design TF in such a way that normal if conditions don't work, you have to call methods.

Comment: The answer is simple: For performance. Tensorflow is thought to be developed as a Graph in order to simplify the compilation to XLA. Read this section of their documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/xla

Answer (score 0):

What you assume is not true, it does have if conditions and control flow, it's just symbolic. For example [tf.case](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/case):

```
f1 = lambda: tf.constant(17)
f2 = lambda: tf.constant(23)
r = tf.case([(tf.less(x, y), f1)], default=f2)
```

It's equivalent to this code:

```
if x < y:
    return 17;
else:
    return 23;
```

There is also [tf.switch_case](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/switch_case) for switch statements.